Dimension of fibre product
Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is dominant morphism of schemes with $Y$ irreducible. Let $p:Z \rightarrow Y$ be quasi finite morphism of schemes such that $\overline{p(Z)} \ne Y$. Let $Z’$ be fibre product of $X$ and $Z$ over $Y$. How do we show that $dim(Z’) < dim(X)$?
All the schemes here are of finite type over field $k$.

try to show that the map from Z' to X is quasifinite and not dominant

How does this imply that dim Z’ is strictly less than dim X? @ChenJiang

it this map is quasifinite, then dim Z' is equal to the dimension of its image in X
